# Is there a lazy select_all option in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a complicated query that I need to run, and it can potentially yield a large result set. I need to iterate linearly through this result set in order to crunch some numbers.

I'm executing the query like so:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)`

find_in_batches Won't work for my use case, as it's critical that I get the records in a custom order. Also, my query returns some fields that aren't part of any models, so I need to get the records as hashes.

The problem is, `select_all` is not lazy (from what I can tell). It loads all of the records into memory. Does Rails have a way to lazily get the results for a custom SQL query? `.lazy` doesn't seem applicable here, as I need custom ordering of the results.

This is possible in other languages (C#, Haskell, JavaScript), so it seems like it would be possible in Ruby.

Comment: You can do `lazy.select`  but `select_all` does not need to be lazy as it's already efficient to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: It's efficient in that it doesn't isntantiate model instances, but it's not efficient, in that it loads everything into memory. If you have millions of results, this is not efficient.

Comment: Can you please explain what you do when you *iterate linearly through this result set* and *crunch some numbers*? There might be another options to solve this, do the calculations in the database for example.

Comment: Yeah. I have time-series data of video/audio watching patterns for a user. I'm iterating over those, and compressing them down into discrete blocks, then summing up those blocks to get a percentage watched. We send the percentage watched, as well as a list of gaps to the browser for display.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `find_each` or `find_in_batches` ActiveRecord methods.

Both query database in configurable-sized batches.

The difference it that `find_each` yields objects one-by-one to block (they are lazy initialized).

`find_in_batches` yields whole batch group.

If you can't use above methods due to custom sorting, what you can do is query the database using `limit` and `offset`. This way you will deal with data in portions. Memory consumption will decrease, but number of queries will increase.

Other solution may be to let database engine perform arithmetic operations, that you need and return calculated result.

Comment: These don't work for my use case, as it's critical that I get the records in a custom order (not by id), otherwise, I can't crunch the numbers without loading it all into memory and sorting. But yes, something like this, except with the behavior of `select_all` (custom ordering, custom fields) is what I am looking for.

Comment: Essentially, I'm looking for something like a cursor, I guess.

Comment: I think that can be impossible using ActiveRecord, however I put 2 more ideas in my answer.

Comment: Yeah. I'd thought about manually batching using `limit` and `offset`. I may end up doing that. The computation is pretty complex, and would be hard to do in raw SQL. I may look into that option, though! Thanks. I'll leave the question open for now to see if anyone does know how to do it without these workarounds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe you're asking for eager_load or preload.
http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Nope, that's not what I'm asking for, unfortunately. I'm trying to run a custom SQL query that does not get entirely loaded all at once, but rather streams the results in as I iterate.